# motivation and applications of barycentric subdivision of a simplicial complex

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff

Question is as in the title:

> What is the motivation and applications of barycentric subdivision of a simplicial complex?

Given a simplicial complex $K$, the barycentric subdivision of $K$ is another "better behaved" simplicial complex $sd(K)$. Moreover, this construction is a functor from the category of simplicial spaces to itself. Furter, this construction does not change the topology, in the sense that, the simplicial map $sd(K)\rightarrow K$ induce a homeomorphism, when passed through geometric realization, $|sd(K)|\rightarrow |K|$.

So, what was the motivation for this construction? I have checked in some references but could not get it completely. Moreover, what are some applications of this construction?

Comment: I am familiar with its interaction with simplicial approximation..

Comment: What's your favoured proof of the excision property of simplicial homology?

Comment: An antecedent of barycentric subdivision in geometry related to simplicial approximation is triangulating surfaces. This is related to simplicial aproximation in the sense that if you use smaller triangles to model a surface, you will get something more similar to the original surface. Barycentric subdivision makes this process of approximation homogeneous and algorithmic.

Comment: @AnginaSeng :) that should be posted as an answer :)

Comment: @Javi yes, I agree